# Multiple web servers one machine, accessed by one FQDN with SSL

Tags: proxy, ssl, svn, iis

I have three webservers running on a single Windows Server 2016 VM. I want to serve all of them via https://secure.mydomain.com and use suffices (ex: /trac, /svn) to access the different webservers.

WebDAV is served by IIS on 443, Trac has it's own webserver (port 8000) and so does SVN (8443).

I've been looking into reverse proxies and IIS URL Rewrite, but they seem to be for multi-server environments.

Can this be done? Preferably with a single PositiveSSL certificate.

Comment: Not particular to IIS, but this is possible with other web servers, so it seems arguably likely that IIS has similar features. Regarding "where" you would redirect the URLs, that would be  `https://localhost:443`, `https://localhost: 8000` and `https://localhost:8443`, respectively. Note, however, that using URL-based proxying will likely break pages unless you take extra steps to rewrite the URLs properly after proxying. Likewise, using a single certificate will also likely complicate things significantly. I would suggest setting up proxying prior to even attempting anything with SSL.

Comment: I feel like URL rewrite is not allowing me to get a path I want. I can create a rule that allows Trac to load (on port 8000) when going to https://secure.mydomain.com but I can't figure out how to add a suffix to differentiate it from SVN and allow me to load both pages.